# How to save user location in react js state using geolocation api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Actually i am getting the coordinates successfully using [react-hook-geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-geolocation) package but the problem here is i don't know how to add that to current state. I want to save the user's location when he submit the form and then combine the userfields and coordinates into one formData object.

Here is the full code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addVisit } from "../../actions/lead";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";
import useGeolocation from "react-hook-geolocation";

const initialState = {
  status: "",
  email: "",
  commentBox: "",
};

const VisitForm = ({ leadId, addVisit, lead: { lead, loading } }) => {
  const geolocation = useGeolocation();

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialState);
  const { status, email, commentBox } = formData;

  const onChange = (e) =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    var coords = {
      lat: geolocation.latitude,
      lng: geolocation.longitude,
    };
    console.log(coords);
    e.preventDefault();
    //addVisit(leadId, formData);
    setFormData(initialState);
  };
  return loading || lead === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <div className="post-form">
      <div className="bg-primary p">
        <h3>Add a Visit</h3>
      </div>
      <form className="form my-1" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <select name="status" value={status} onChange={onChange}>
          <option value="0">* Select Lead Status</option>
          <option value="Met">Met</option>
          <option value="Not_met">Not met</option>
          <option value="Close_Lead">Close Lead</option>
          <option value="Done">Done</option>
        </select>
        <div className="form-group">
          <select
            className="form-group"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={onChange}
          >
            <option value="0">* Select Person</option>
            {lead.personDetails.map((person) => (
              <option key={person._id} value={person.email}>
                {person.name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
        <textarea
          name="commentBox"
          cols="30"
          rows="5"
          placeholder="Any additional Comment"
          value={commentBox}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-dark my-1" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  lead: state.lead,
});

VisitForm.propTypes = {
  addVisit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  lead: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addVisit })(VisitForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to combine two objects together, you can use the Spread operator:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    const coords = {
      lat: geolocation.latitude,
      lng: geolocation.longitude,
    };
    const newData = {...formData, ...coords}
    setFormData(newData)
    addVisit(leadId, newData);
  };
```

Comment: Actually, I have tried doing the same you mentioned but its not working for me, its just sending the original formData object without copying coords.

Comment: Sending to where? The formData state will get both original object properties and coords. If you are trying to use formData in the same method, it is wrong because the state is not updated immediately and only after rerender. You should rather use {...formData, ...coords} in your request instead then. I updated the answer if it helps.

Comment: Pardon my language i should have said returning instead of sending, your new edit is working fine. Thanks a lot.